# Random number return in if/else

Tags: javascript

OK people a really beginner question. I have written a function and it is working fine. Random check, If / else check... yes.

```
function getRandom(num) {
    var myNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    return myNum;
}

if (getRandom(10) > 5) {
    alert("Number bigger 5");
} else {
    alert("Number smaller 5");
}
```

But now I want to add the random value in the alert.  if I expand my alert statement with `getRandom(10)` i will get another number not the first one..

```
 alert("Number bigger 5" + "Random number was: " + getRandom(10) );
```

I know it must be very very simple and I have to store my first generated number in a var or something like that. Can you please give some advise ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*i have to store my first generated number in a var*, Yes precisely you need to do that.

```
var num = getRandom(10);
if ( num > 5 ){
    alert("Number bigger 5" + "Random number was: " + num );
}
else {
    alert("Number smaller 5" + "Random number was: " + num );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the random number in a variable, and use that for the check and alert:

```
var num= getRandom(10)
if ( num > 5 ){
    alert("Number bigger 5 Random number was: " + num );
}
else {
    alert("Number smaller 5 Random number was: " + num );
}
```